# Why is the word 'Block' used along with a number to indicate the rocket version?

Tags: rockets, engineering

Why is the word "block" used to indicate a rocket's version? Based on usage, I sort of understand what is meant, but I am confused why the word "Block" is used.

Examples:

- Falcon 9 Block 5
- SLS Block I

Comment: I was trying to guess, but nothing seemed logical. Engine block version?

Comment: Thanks Russell, it is an exact duplicate of that question and I appreciated your answer. Funny thing is I searched this site for a question like that and couldn't find it. (I always search first) anyway, appreciate it. We can link or close this question and defer to that one.

Comment: Unless keeping this question helps people find the answer.

Comment: When a question is marked as duplicate, it doesn't vanish, and can indeed help people find answers, depending on what they search on.  While prior research is appreciated, there's nothing particularly negative about having your question marked as duplicate. So ask away!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially it just means "version".  Example: the [Apollo Command Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Command/Service_Module#Development_history).

Sometimes in Europe they use "tranche". Example : the [Eurofighter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurofighter_Typhoon_variants#Series_production_aircraft).

Other places sometimes use "Mark". Examples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_I).

Why is "version" not just good enough?  Can't give definitive answer, it's probably rooted in corporate/industry history on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Thanks. Canon camera uses 'Mark' to indicate version as well. I don't know the origin, but it seems more like a version indicator than the word 'block'.

Comment: In historical use, the difference between new models of a plane and a "block" of a plane was that the blocks were minor updates that, in theory, could be applied in the field rather than requiring a new part.  The nomenclature has stuck.

Answer (score -2):

It's just nomenclature the manufacturers chose, it doesn't mean anything in and of itself.

Comment: To whomever downvoted me, I'd appreciate some reasoning why. If I wasn't detailed enough I'll take it, but otherwise it seems petty.